# What's the best (fastest for performance) code in PHP to resize very large images (3000x6000px)?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, jpeg, image-resizing

I found many examples on how to resize an image however I'm curious about what's the best (fastest) code in PHP to do it and for very large images (over 1000px).

I wrote this simple example... anyone knows a better implementation?

```
<?php

    $filename = 'myimage.jpg';
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

    $scale = 50; // resize the image to 50% of its original width and height

    $width = imagesx($image);
    $width_scaled = $width * $scale/100;
    $height = imagesy($image);
    $height_scaled = $height * $scale/100;

    $image_scaled = imagecreatetruecolor($width_scaled, $height_scaled);
    imagecopyresampled($image_scaled, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_scaled, $height_scaled, $width, $height);

?>
```

Comment: If you pre-calculate `$scale/100` once, you may save a cycle...

Comment: I think you may be better off by ditching php functions and use imagemagick for the resize or something similar.

Comment: thank you All! I've found this useful PHP extension at http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.scaleimage.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [imagecopyresized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php). I think it's faster because you skip one step. However, the actual resizing is probably the most time consuming, so you won't gain much unless you find a separate library/plugin that is faster.